# Which target feature do I need to add to get tracing in an RCP app?

Tags: logging, eclipse-rcp, trace

I am upgrading a 3.x RCP app from Kepler to 2020-3 and have just noticed that the preference page 'General > Tracing' is missing.

I have changed the the project structure from plugin-based to feature-based and have included what I understand to be the standard RCP components in the target definition.

The plugin spy indicates that I need `org.eclipse.ui.trace` and this is not loaded by my target.

[image: target components]

Which feature do I need to add to get tracing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the Eclipse PDE feature - `org.eclipse.pde` "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment"

You can also add individual existing plug-ins to your feature rather than including all of an existing feature.

Comment: Thanks. Is this something that one just knows or is there a way to track down the locations of bundles?

Comment: You can search the feature.xml files in the features directory of your Eclipse installation, not sure if there is any better way.